# Use redux + react when render the array to print three times, in the last two results is undefined, the third is the result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
render() {
    const { history, photos } = this.props
    return (
        <section>
          {
            console.log(photos)
          }
        </section>
       )
}

chrome console:
index.js:134 action @@router/UPDATE_PATH @ 15:56:43.041

index.js:31 undefined

client.js:53 [HMR] connected

index.js:31 undefined

index.js:31 [Object, Object, Object]

index.js:134  action MAINSLIDE @ 15:56:43.680
```

Comment: Can you post all your code?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please add some more context. Where does the prop 'photos' come from and how does your component look like?